# Spinnaker OAuth 2.0 with github Now everyone can login

Tags: oauth, spinnaker

I enabled OAuth 2.0 with github now everyone who has github and not in my organization unit can login to spinnaker
How do I restrict this ?

Spinnaker 1.5.2
Clouddriver 1.0.2-20171221211744 (2017-12-21

Comment: were you able to achieve this OAuth login?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible in the current Spinnaker release. I recently saw on the Spinnaker Slack channel that [there is a PR](https://github.com/spinnaker/fiat/issues/188) to fix this that has been merged, so it should get released soon(just not sure when).

I would recommend joining the [Spinnaker Slack channel](https://join.spinnaker.io/) as it is pretty active, and can help you stay current on what is being worked on.

Answer (score -1):

Also try posting to community.spinnaker.io